# Suppress content scaling on retina devices

Tags: mono, xamarin.ios, playn, ikvm

Hi I am working on small project in a framework called PlayN that uses mono for IOS development.

I am having problems understanding the content scale factor and how to disable its automagic stretching and scaling.

I would like to manually downscale and upscale images using a layout manager (mostly to support different layouts and also more resolutions(for android) and orientations).

Currently when loading a 960x640 (in opengl) im drawing outside the 480x320 frame of the 3gs as expected (I only see the upper left half of the image) but when I load the same image on the retina device it will use the content scale factor of 2 and scale my 960 image to 1920 (so I can still only see the upper half part of the image, but stretched) since it thinks its a low resolution image (not marked @2x). Can I disable this automatic scaling without disabling the larger frame buffer of the view?

I am no IOS developer and any help would be gladly accepted.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to make a hi-res version of the image, then name it `YourImage@2x.png`.

This is how iOS handles retina displays.

See here about @2x images: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html